# 'Int1' is not convertible to 'Bool' error with ternary operator in initializer

Tags: swift

The following code is giving me an error in Xcode 8.2.1:

```
UIColor(red: redSwitch.isOn ? 1 : 0, green: greenSwitch.isOn ? 1 : 0, blue: blueSwitch.isOn ? 1 : 0 )
```

The error is:

> 'Int1' is not convertible to 'Bool'

Why is that? `redSwitch.isOn` works fine in an `if` statement condition. The Apple reference [documentation says `UISwitch.isOn` returns `Bool`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiswitch/1623690-ison).

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Also, consider adding some parenthesis. They may (or may not) make a difference, but it add to readability.

Comment: @Hamish, that fixed it! Strange error message for missing a parameter... You should post your comment as an answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a rubbish error message, but the problem is simply that you're missing the `alpha:` parameter from `UIColor`'s [`init(red:green:blue:alpha:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor/1621925-init) initialiser.

```
let color = UIColor(red: redSwitch.isOn ? 1 : 0, green: greenSwitch.isOn ? 1 : 0,
                    blue: blueSwitch.isOn ? 1 : 0, alpha: 1)
```

From what I can tell, the source of the weird error message seems to be the use of the ternary operator in a `convenience` initialiser call where you're missing one of the parameters.

A more minimal example would be:

```
class Foo {
    convenience init(a: Int, b: Int) {}
}

let f = Foo(a: true ? 1 : 0) // 'Int1' is not convertible to 'Bool'
```

I went ahead and filed a bug over this error, [SR-3839](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3839).

Answer (score 0):

Another take on this bug.

```
import CoreGraphics
let hit: Bool = true
let returnStroke: Bool = false
let rotation: CGFloat = (hit ? 90 : 120)
rotation *= returnStroke ? -1.0 : 1.0 // 'Int1' is not convertible to 'Bool'
```

The real problem is that `rotation` should be a variable and not a constant. Changing `let` to `var` makes the "convertible" error disappear, and the code will run.

While keeping `rotation` as a constant, no amount of parenthesis in the right side expression would make the correct error message appear, either. That message being "Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable..."